# Blender objects moving together - not proportional editing

Tags: animation, mesh, 3d-mouse

I was working on an animation in Blender, and for it I was essentially breaking apart a joined mesh... however when I went to move those joined bits (I separated them using <kbd>P</kbd>) it worked, at first, then when I moved the animation along the whole object jumped to where I had moved the broken part...

**This is not Proportional Editing.** I have looked everywhere for an answer...

Comment: Make sure you they are not children to a moved object. Also double check if you have not inserted a keyframe accidently for the wrong objects.